# Populate userform listview

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fill a listview in a userform from a range in Sheet1

This is the code I'm using

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
'Set some of the properties for the ListView
With Me.ListView1
    .HideColumnHeaders = False
    .View = lvwReport
End With

'Declare the variables
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim LstItem As ListItem
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ColCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'Set the source worksheet
Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Set the source range
Set rngData = wksSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'Add the column headers
For Each rngCell In rngData.Rows(1).Cells
    Me.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rngCell.Value, Width:=90
Next rngCell

'Count the number of rows in the source range
RowCount = rngData.Rows.Count

'Count the number of columns in the source range
ColCount = rngData.Columns.Count

'Fill the ListView
For i = 2 To RowCount
    Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(i, 1).Value) '==> Error here
    For j = 2 To ColCount
        LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(i, j).Value
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

But the problem is that I always get this error

Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch

Any help plz ?

Thank u in advance

Comment: seems that your range `wksSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion` has errors like `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, `#DIV!0` or etc..

Comment: even when I change it to wksSource.Range("A1:B5") I still have the same problem

Comment: it doesn't matter how you refers to your range. Check whether this range contains errors like `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, `#DIV!0` or etc..

Comment: no it doesn't .. it doesn't even contain any formulas .. just some text

Comment: any chance to see your workbook?

Comment: sure .. this is a sample http://www.sendspace.com/file/dgr56s

Comment: it seems that you're using another listview control rather than me..Try to use this one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KXEVX.png

Comment: thank u so much . when I try to add this one I get this error "ClassFactory cannot supply requested class"

Comment: try this workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/se8xsz4ilqmhcz0/test_simoco.xlsm

Comment: thank u so much . seems I got some system issues .. I really appreciate ur help

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(i, 1).Value)
```

with:

```
Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(i, 1).Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:
Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(i, 1).Value)

With:
Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(i, 1).Value)

Try removing "Set LstItem = "